# Google maps прицепить свой класс к иконкам маркеров

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Хочется стилизовать подсказки title: выводимые при простом наведении мышкой на иконку маркера. Подскажите как сделать, куда смотреть?

Пробовал к иконке класс прицепить при загрузке, как-то не очень выходит. JS знаю слабовато.

```
var icotitle = document.querySelector('img');
window.onload = () => {
  icotitle.className = 'Tips2';
  console.log(icotitle)
}
```

Comment: `element.classList.add('class_name_here');`

Comment: class="gmnoprint" под ним лежит иконка img без класса, как прикрутить класс к иконке на гуглокарте?  поиск решений пока ответа не дает... есть вот такое решение google.maps.event.addListener(YOURMARKER,'mouseover',function(){$(".gm-style   div").addClass("markerClass")});                        
google.maps.event.addListener(YOURMARKER,'mouseout',function(){$(".gm-style div").removeClass("markerClass")});        только как его переделать чтобы класс сразу цепляло?

Comment: вобщем первая проблема в том, что карта грузится через фрейм